# How Can WYSIHTML5 output inline CSS?

Tags: css, wysihtml5

I am running WYSIHTML5 to allow myself to enter email text and format it for sending as HTML. However when I view HTML of the formatted text I get classes associated with elements for Colors. This is expected behavior but since I need to send the output in an email hence I would like to have those colors to be in Inline CSS, since I cannot attach CSS files with the email like that. Example here

```
<span class="wysiwyg-color-green">Testing</span>
```

That is if I select green color for text: `Testing`. Is there any way to modify that green to become part of html itself like

```
<span style="color:green">Testing</span>
```

I have tried to search for this but could not find, so I am not asking without first looking for it. If anybody could please just point somewhere. Even a link to any guide to this, will do. I do not wish that you spend time writing code for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it with php :

```
str_replace ( 'class="wysiwyg-color-green"', 'style="color:green"' ,$html)
```

You can do the same with javascript, altrough it's always safer to do everything server-side.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Comment: Jean thanks for your answer, it looks good and simple too. However I was hoping if this could be done by JavaScript itself. Your answer will work though so +1 for it while I wait for a JavaScript solution if any

Comment: I updated, but i wouldn't count on javascript, especially for sending e-mails. Javascript can be disabled or messed with. Php can't.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the javascript code I used but may be a good idea to heed Jean-Georges warning above:

```
replaceColorStylesWithInlineCss = function (htmlContents){
    result = htmlContents.replace('class="wysiwyg-color-black"', 'class="wysiwyg-color-black" style="color:black"');
    result = result.replace('class="wysiwyg-color-silver"', 'class="wysiwyg-color-silver" style="color:silver"');
    result = result.replace('class="wysiwyg-color-gray"', 'class="wysiwyg-color-gray" style="color:gray"');
    result = result.replace('class="wysiwyg-color-maroon"', 'class="wysiwyg-color-maroon" style="color:maroon"');
    result = result.replace('class="wysiwyg-color-red"', 'class="wysiwyg-color-red" style="color:red"');
    result = result.replace('class="wysiwyg-color-purple"', 'class="wysiwyg-color-purple" style="color:purple"');
    result = result.replace('class="wysiwyg-color-green"', 'class="wysiwyg-color-green" style="color:green"');
    result = result.replace('class="wysiwyg-color-olive"', 'class="wysiwyg-color-olive" style="color:olive"');
    result = result.replace('class="wysiwyg-color-navy"', 'class="wysiwyg-color-navy" style="color:navy"');
    result = result.replace('class="wysiwyg-color-blue"', 'class="wysiwyg-color-blue" style="color:blue"');
    result = result.replace('class="wysiwyg-color-orange"', 'class="wysiwyg-color-orange" style="color:orange"');
    return result
};
```

Note: I kept the wysiwyg styles in there because I'm saving to the db and want it to display properly in the wysihtml5 section when I load it again. DRY it up if you're clever.